# What does ... mean in var_dump php?

Tags: php, var-dump

This is an example output:

```
class Framework\Configuration\Driver\Ini#3 (2) { protected $_parsed => array(0) { } private $_inspector => class Framework\Inspector#4 (4) { protected $_class => ... protected $_meta => array(3) { 'class' => array(0) { ... } 'properties' => array(0) { ... } 'methods' => array(0) { ... } } protected $_properties => array(0) { } protected $_methods => array(0) { } } }
```

For example there is `protected $_class => ..`

What does ... mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have xdebug installed?! It will limit max depth of var_dump to 3 level.

Read more here: http://www.xdebug.org/docs/display

You can change it by changing xdebug.var_display_max_depth variable.

Comment: @KorayTugay, Yeah xdebug settings are in php.ini but you may need to add this option manually. Search for other xdebug settings there and add it near them.